# slc.autocategorize failing with Plone collections

Tags: plone, categories

I am using slc.autocategorize to automatically tag folder items in order to build a complex collection of materials on my Plone 4.3 site (think multi-dimensional arrays). The tool is tagging files (tags are visible in view mode), but the tags are not being recognized by my collections unless I manually touch every file by opening it and resaving it or by copying it and pasting back into place.

I have checked the client and z2 logs and am not seeing any errors. Does anyone know if this is a compatability issue? Is there something that I am failing to do involving the index? Are there any other tools I should be looking at to auto-categorize folder contents?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Seems a catalog issue. Try to reindex the whole catalog: if tags magically appears I'm right.
I don't know this add-on but probably a `reindexObject` is missing somewhere after tagging action

Comment: @keul: just looking at the code, it just does a `obj.setSubject(...)` without manually triggering a reindex in an event handler. I think event handlers are after the initial indexing, right?

Comment: Then after the `.setSubject` you can add a `obj.reindexObect(idxs=['Subject'])`

Comment: @keul your initial thought was absolutely right. I appended the events.py and it resolved the issue. Thank you.

Comment: @user3870504 think about open an issue to the maintainer, or provide a pull request.